# How to listen for changes in state object loaded from API?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If I set state object like this:

```
const state: {
    tools: {
        tool1: {
            status: true.
            state: 
        },
        tool2: {
            status: false.
            state: 1
        }
    }
}
```

on view side everything is changing correctly when I change for example status using mutation.

But If i set tools using API response:

```
state.tools = response.tools;
```

where response is 100% identical nothing happens. State object has changes which can also be seen in Vue debuger.

So what I have tried is to add
const state: {
        tools: {
            tool0: {
                status: true.
                state: 
            }
        }
    }

and added tool1 and tool1 from ajax (so my object had 3 child element tool0, tool1, tool3). So if I trigger change on tool1 or tool2 (loaded by ajax) nothing happened. But when I trigger change on tool0 (hardcoded before) everything works fine - in this case also settings set on ajax loaded content are applied.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set the state using `Vue.set`?

Ref: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

From the docs:

> **Mutations Follow Vue's Reactivity Rules**
>
> Since a Vuex store's state is made reactive by Vue...
>
> ...
>
> When adding new properties to an Object, you should either: Use `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)` or ...

You are adding new props here. You should set it as follows:

```
Vue.set(state, tools, response.tools)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Missed that... Since I was changing from arrays to objects. On arrays it works OK without Vue.set hack ;)

Comment: I would love to know how to do this in a lower down sub-component. Whenever I try what I assume is the equivalent `this.$set(state, tools, response.tools)` I just get 'state is not defined'.

Comment: The state needs to be referenced as `this.$store.state` when you are in a Vue component. In Vuex, as per the [api docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html), state gets passed as a function parameter to action and mutation handlers. So if you define your action handler as `yourCustomAction: function({ commit, state }, payload) {...}`, then you can access `state` directly. I still prefer to define my action as `myCustomAction: function(context, payload){...}` and access state as `context.state`.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general answer, the syntax of Vue.set is:

> Vue.set(object, key, value)

So if you use this somewhere at a deep level, you get:

> let object = state.someLargeObject.SomeObjectInsideIt
>
> Vue.set(object, key, value)